# OpenGL|ES on a desktop PC

Tags: opengl, opengl-es

I'm working on a OpenGL project that I would like to port to embedded systems that support OpenGL|ES.

Since OpenGL|ES is a subset of OpenGL how hard would it be to compile my OpenGL application on an embedded system? (Assuming that my OpenGL code is in the limits of OpenGL|ES)

I guess what I'm wondering is: is it possible to dircetly wrap my OpenGL calls with MACROS to make it compatible with OpenGL|ES API call names? Are there any calls specific to OpenGL|ES that I would have to implement?

Comment: Is it OpenGL ES or OpenGL ES 2.0? This does matter.

Answer (score 1):

There's always [dgles](https://web.archive.org/web/20081025045323/http://developer.hybrid.fi/dgles/index.html).  [Sami Kyostila](http://www.unrealvoodoo.org/projects/maemo) made some [updates](https://web.archive.org/web/20120717050636/http://unrealvoodoo.org/git/dgles.git/) to it.

Answer (score 1):

1. AMD has such an emulator  ([Beyond3D news](http://www.beyond3d.com/content/news/393))
2. ARM provides GL ES emulation ([MaliDeveloper](http://www.malideveloper.com/opengl-es-20-emulator.php))
3. The general list of [available emulators](http://soulbuzz.net/?p=225).