# Develop for OpenGL ES on the desktop

Tags: opengl, cross-platform, opengl-es, opengl-to-opengles

I'm developing a desktop OpenGL application, and I want to make sure it'll be compatible to OpenGL ES, so that it'll be easier to port it to mobile platforms later.

What's the best way to make sure I'm using only the OpenGL ES specifications in my software?

Comment: Similar question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2476929/opengles-on-a-desktop-pc but this is not exactly what I'm after.

Comment: Are you targeting ES 1.1 or 2.0?

Comment: I think 1.1, since 2.0 is still not that common. But I'll be glad to hear about both options.

Comment: If you target OpenGL ES 2.0 and Desktop 3.0>, you can also try OpenREng ( openreng.sourceforge.net ). You just change the cmake opengl platform to mobile and related installed libraries are used. You can try PowerVR OpenGL ES 2.0 emulators, which use OpenGL 2.1 underneath (if I remember correctly)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you occasionally build/run against [dgles](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2476929/opengles-on-a-desktop-pc/2478718#2478718) you should be set.

Other than that just pop open the ES 1.1 spec from time to time and double-check whatever you're using is in it.

Comment: If some software could pop open the ES 1.1 specs, and double check whatever I'm using, I'm sure it'll do a much better job than I would ;-). But thanks!

Answer (score 3):

There is an OpenGL ES emulator that you can use.  [Here's a link](http://opengles-book.com/downloads.html)